# Aggregate with range condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with 2 types of documents :

```
{"_id" : 172347106,"name" : "product 1", "type" : "product"}
{"_id" : 135377126,"name" : "product 2", "type" : "product"}
{"_id" : 135378126,"name" : "product 3", "type" : "product"}
{"price" : 8,"id_start" : 172347000,"id_end" : 173347106, "type" : "price"}
{"price" : 6,"id_start" : 135377000,"id_end" : 136377126, "type" : "price"}
```

I want a second collection with only products with there price (the price can be found with the id which is between id_start and id_end) like :

```
{"_id" : 172347106,"name" : "product 1", "price" : 8}
{"_id" : 135377126,"name" : "product 2", "price" : 6}
{"_id" : 135378126,"name" : "product 3", "price" : 6}
```

When documents are in separates collections I do the the following query :

```
db.getCollection("product").find({}).forEach( function(myProduct) {
     db.getCollection("price").findOne({$and: [ { "id_start":{$lt: parseInt(myProduct._id) } }, {"id_end":{$gt: parseInt(myProduct._id)}}]})
});
```

How can I do with Aggregation framework ? (or maybe map/reduce ?)

Thank you very much !

Comment: You have already asked this question, and it yet remains unanswered. You do not need to ask it twice.

Comment: Not the same question, here I'm in the same collection. In the other post I want a solution for 2 separate collections. But I can ask in the other post if you prefer

Comment: Please add details to that question. You are asking the same question because the basic premise of "match on range" is the heart of the question here.

Comment: I add precision on other post, but I think the simpler would be to delete other post and let this one open. Possible ?

Comment: Please amend your existing question. It's not a simple question, And I did ask you for details there. So you can add that to the post as well.